# How to install get-pip.py for Portable Python 2.7.6.1

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip, portable-python

I have to work with python for a university project – unfortunately I’m a total newbie and now I have serious problems in installing pip. We are obliged to use Portable Python 2.7.6.1. Every time I try to run the get-pip.py file, Python opens config.py and shows me the error message “ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': DebugOutput instance has no attribute 'closed'”. My operating system is Windows 8.
What can I do? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
App\Scripts\easy_install.exe pip
```

From the [Portable Python website](http://portablepython.com/doc/2.7/easy-install/):

> One of the options for adding new packages/libraries to Portable Python is easy-install. This approach will work for simple libraries but for some more complex it might not as in some cases easy-install adds files outside of the Portable Python folder, which makes this not a portable installation.

As far as I know, the Portable Python project is abandoned. For Windows, this project picks up where Portable Python left off: https://winpython.github.io